# Multiple graphs using Core Plot on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, core-plot

I have an app that requires an unknown number of graphs to show, depending on how many sensors are attached to the iPad. I have X numbers of `NSArray`s containing X `NSNumber`s which are updating live; the graphs need to update along with the data (i.e. live as well).

My problem occurs when I use [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/HighLevelDesignOverview). How do I create multiple graphs dynamically? I am new to Objective-C so perhaps it's just an issue with me.

If I create a graph and the corresponding delegate methods which is required to add data? Can someone give an overview of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code will be helpful if you want to add multiple graphs to one
>   view. You can simple add a graph by calling:
>
> CGRect rect = CGRectMake(160, 99, 864, 223);    plot1 = [self
>   getGraphWithRect:rect identifier:@"1"];

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  sense01
//
//  Created by Morten Ydefeldt on 8/16/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 ydefeldt. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SenseManager.h"
#import "Sensor.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize statusIndicator;
@synthesize values;
@synthesize recordButton;
@synthesize plot;

-(void)senseIsConnected:(BOOL)status
{
    if(status)
    {
        statusIndicator.text = @"Connected";
        [recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        statusIndicator.text = @"Disconnected";
        [recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_notactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}

- (void)newDataFromSensor:(id)sensor{

    for(id key in sensor) {
        id value = [sensor objectForKey:key];

        //textView.text = [value description];

        [self pointReceived:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[value getRealWorldData] intValue]]];
    }}



-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector
{

    return CGPointMake(proposedDisplacementVector.x, 0);
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
        newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
    }
    return newRange;


}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.05 blue:0.05 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    manager = [[SenseManager alloc] init];
    manager.delegate  = self;
    [manager openConnection];


    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 99);
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.05 blue:0.05 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(160, 99, 864, 223);
    plot1 = [self getGraphWithRect:rect identifier:@"1"];

    rect = CGRectMake(160, 322, 864, 223);
    plot2 = [self getGraphWithRect:rect identifier:@"2"];

    rect = CGRectMake(160, 545, 864, 223);
    plot3 = [self getGraphWithRect:rect identifier:@"3"];


    NSMutableArray *ContentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:200];
    self.values = ContentArray;
}

-(CPTXYGraph *)getGraphWithRect:(CGRect)rect identifier:(NSString*)identifier{


    plot = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    CPTGraphHostingView *layerHostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    layerHostingView.collapsesLayers = NO;
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph = plot;


    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace* )plot.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length: CPTDecimalFromDouble(60.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length: CPTDecimalFromDouble(50.0)];

    CPTScatterPlot *line = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];

    //Fill colors
    float c= 0.2;
    plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:c green:c blue:c alpha:1]];
    plot.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:c green:c blue:c alpha:1]];
    plot.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

    //Plot border
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.2;
    plot.borderLineStyle = lineStyle;

    //Plot padding
    plot.paddingBottom = 5;
    plot.paddingLeft = 5;
    plot.paddingRight = 5;
    plot.paddingTop = 5;

    //axis range
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)plot.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");

    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:15.0];
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:25.0];

    y.minorTickLength = 0;
    y.majorTickLength = 0;
    x.minorTickLength = 0;
    x.majorTickLength = 0;

    //axis theming
    c = 0.4;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:c green:c blue:c alpha:1];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 0.7f;
    y.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;


    //label theming
    CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    x.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
    y.labelTextStyle = textStyle;

    //grid theming
    c = 0.3;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:c green:c blue:c alpha:1];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 0.1f;
    x.minorGridLineStyle = lineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle = lineStyle;


    //curve theming
    lineStyle.miterLimit = 1.0f;
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    line.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    line.identifier = identifier;
    line.dataSource = self;


    //plotsymbol
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    CPTGradient *blueGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:62.0f/255.0f green:112.0/255.0f blue:184.0f/255.0f alpha:1] endingColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:43.0f/255.0f green:63.0/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = lineStyle;
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:blueGradient];
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(11.0, 11.0);
    line.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;

    [plot addPlot:line];

    [self.view addSubview:layerHostingView];

    return plot;



}

#pragma mark

-(void)pointReceived:(NSNumber *) point{

    [self.values addObject:point];

    self.statusIndicator.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", point];
    self.statusIndicator.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.values count]];

    CPTPlot *first = [plot plotWithIdentifier:@"2"];
    [first insertDataAtIndex:self.values.count-1 numberOfRecords:1];

    CPTPlot *secondPlot = [plot plotWithIdentifier:@"3"];
    [secondPlot insertDataAtIndex:self.values.count-1 numberOfRecords:1];

    NSLog(@"LOL");

}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot{

    return [values count];

}


-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot*)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX){
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:index];

    }else{
        return [self yValueForIndex:index];
    }

}

-(NSNumber *) yValueForIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    return [self.values objectAtIndex:index];

}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    statusIndicator = nil;
    recordButton = nil;
    [self setRecordButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void) portStatusChanged
{

}

- (void) readBytesAvailable:(UInt32)length
{



//    myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
//    int bytesRead = [rscMgr read:rxBuffer Length:length];
//    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
//        [myString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",((char *)rxBuffer)[i]]];
//    }
//    textView.text = myString;
//    //textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textView.text,myString];
//    //    NSArray *arrayValues = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//    //    textView.text = [arrayValues objectAtIndex:1];
//    //    statusIndicator.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[arrayValues count]];
//    //  arrayValues = nil;

}

-(IBAction)Write:(id)sender{

    [self pointReceived:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20]];

}

- (IBAction)recordButton:(id)sender {



    if (record) {
        record = NO;
        [recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [manager activateDataFromSense:NO];
    }
    else{

        [recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [manager activateDataFromSense:YES];
        record = YES;
    }

}


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create as many graphs as you need. Make a hosting view for each one and lay them out however you want. The hosting view is a subclass of `UIView` so you can use all of the standard layout techniques and container views.

Depending on the look you want to achieve, an alternative is to use one graph that holds multiple plots. Create each one normally and use `-addPlot:` to add them to the graph.

All of your plots can share a datasource, although they don't have to. Set the `identifier` on each plot to a unique value. In the datasource methods, check the `identifier` on the `plot` parameter and use that to decide what data to return.

Comment: I am trying the following but line 201 fails.

    [secondPlot insertDataAtIndex:self.values.count-1 numberOfRecords:1];

But the strange thing is that:

    [thisPlot insertDataAtIndex:self.values.count-1 numberOfRecords:1];

That line work just fine. 

The whole code:
http://pastebin.com/7r1jR0Ku

Comment: Did you find a reason why the insertion in the second plot fails? Even I am facing the same issue.